# Генератор документации TypeScript .d.ts

Tags: typescript, документация

Есть  file.d.ts с декларациями
Если сделать :

```
typedoc --mode file --out docs/ .  --includeDeclarations --excludeExternals
```

То не формируются описания внешних типов, которые цепляются в

```
/// <reference path="../public/i.d.ts"/>;
```

Если убрать --excludeExternals
То захватываются все типы из внешних ссылок-деклараций.
Хотелось бы, чтобы в доку попали только необходимые, которые использованы в первом файле - источнике
Может я не нашел какого то ключика ?
Может нужно использовать не typedoc ?

Comment: Ммммм, эстивацияяяяя - лень искать. 1.что ты получаешь на выходе 2.почему не `import "../public/i.d.ts"`

Comment: Импорт нельзя, потому что у нас javascript-машина старенькая первый ECMAC

Comment: 1. ты пропустил первый вопрос. 2. в каком файле используется `/// <reference path` 3. и вообще - отредактируй вопрос, добавь минимальный тестовый пример ...

Comment: напрмер: есть файл А используем команду Б получаем на выходе файл Ц

Comment: Есть файл x.d.ts

В нем описаны 2  интерфейса  A и B

`---   declare interface A ...
    declare interface B
---`
eсть файл   y.d.ts
В нем есть строчки
`---
/// <reference path="../public/x.d.ts"/>;
declare function  aaa(i:A):void
---`
Делаем typedoc файлу y.d.ts
Получаем на выходе доку с описанием функции  aaa и интерфейса A и B
А хотелось бы только  aaa и A

Сорри так и не понял как делать перевод строк

Comment: ©отредактируй вопрос